# trouble getting twig template to see css file

Tags: css, html, iis, twig

I'm a newbie to Twig and I'm having some trouble with it. I'm using wamp64 with php version 7 on a pc. My file structure is as follows:

```
C:/composer/vendor/composer
C:/composer/vendor/container-interop
C:/composer/vendor/nikic
C:/composer/vendor/pimple
C:/composer/vendor/psr
C:/composer/vendor/slim
C:/composer/vendor/symfony
C:/composer/vendor/twig

C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/project
C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/project/assets
C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/project/js
C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/project/templates
```

I have this file, called `bootstrap.php`, that I include in my project:

```
<?php

require_once 'C:/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/project/templates');

 // Instantiate our Twig
//$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
?>
```

Here is my layout file, `_layout.twig`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/scripts.js"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="http://localhost/people-on-the-move/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
{% block mask %}

{% endblock %}  

{% block submit %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my home page, `home.html`:

```
{% extends '_layout.twig' %}

{% block mask %}
    {% include 'mask.html' %}
{% endblock %}


{% block submit %}
    {% include 'submit.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

But when I view http://localhost/project in my browser, I see no css has been applied. I've looked at the documentation for how to add a css page, but I have found it very confusing. Where does the css file need to go? Do I need to install something else? Is composer supposed to be inside my project directory? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The folders `people-on-the-move` and `css` are non-existing in the file structure you've mentioned.

Comment: @Emma - thanks, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm going to try django. This is just confusing me.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why you'd use twig in such a way while you could just use Symfony. Anyhow, depending on how your project is set up you CSS should be at `/people-on-the-move/css/styles.css` as your link tag suggests. If you are using Symfony the / path on the browser is actually /public, so the CSS should be located at /public/people-on-the-move/css/styles.css.

Better practice should be using the assets system in Symfony, but since you aren't really using Symfony yet I'd start looking here: [Symfony twig and assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why you are suggesting `twig` should not be used stand-alone. It's perfectly legit and possible, not everyone needs all the functions `symfony` has to offer

Comment: I know, and Twig is awesome standalone. But he's already including Symfony so that's why I'm wondering why.